# Insert в триггере mysql, получение только что добавленных значений

Tags: sql, база-данных, mysqli

Я написал небольшой триггер

```
CREATE DEFINER = CURRENT_USER TRIGGER 

`Quiz`.`ThemeSite_AFTER_INSERT` AFTER INSERT ON `ThemeSite` FOR EACH ROW

INSERT INTO `quiz`.`settings` (`nameConfig`, `value`) VALUES ( + "Chat", '0');
```

Который просто при добавлении в одну таблицу значений добавляет в другую таблицу значения. Но мне нужно, чтоб в `nameConfig` добавлялось `ThemeSite.nameTheme` которое я только что добавил. Я пытался добавлять это: `new.nameTheme` в первое значение, но это было неверно.  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Триггер добавляется, но когда я пытаюсь заинсертить значения, чтоб отработал триггер пишет ошибку: [image]

Проблема именно в триггере. Без него всё добавляет.
Вот архитектура таблицы, в которую триггер должен добавить значения:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В тригере надо использовать одинарные кавычки для строковых значений и конкатенация строк осуществляется с помощью функции [concat()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat).

```
INSERT INTO `quiz`.`settings` (`nameConfig`, `value`) VALUES (concat(new.themeName, 'Chat'), '0');
```